# Laravel "Cannot add foreign key constraint" - Migrate

Tags: laravel, command, foreign-keys, migrate, seed

I have a problem with a foreign key.
I have a user who has a sex:

My migration users :

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('nom');
            $table->string('prenom');
            $table->string('adresse');
            $table->integer('cp');
            $table->string('ville');
            $table->string('email')->unique();
            $table->string('password');
            $table->rememberToken();
            $table->timestamps();
            $table->tinyInteger('admin')->nullable();
        });

    Schema::table('users', function ($table) {
        $table->integer('sexe_id')->unsigned();
        $table->foreign('sexe_id')->references('id')->on('sexes');
    });
}

/**
 * Reverse the migrations.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function down()
{
    Schema::drop('users');
}`
```

My sexe migration :

```
/**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('sexes', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('libelle');
            $table->timestamps();
        });    
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::drop('sexes');
    }
```

My sexes seeder :

```
class SexesTableSeeder extends Seeder
{
    /**
     * Run the database seeds.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function run()
    {
        DB::table('sexes')->insert([
            [
                'libelle' => 'Homme',
                'created_at' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
                'updated_at' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
            ],
            [
                'libelle' => 'Femme',
                'created_at' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
                'updated_at' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
            ]
        ]);    
    }
}
```

My users seeder :

```
class UsersTableSeeder extends Seeder
{
    /**
     * Run the database seeds.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function run()
    {
        DB::table('users')->insert([
            [
                'name' => 'admin',
                'nom' => 'Virlois',
                'prenom' => 'Peter',
                'sexe_id' => 1,
                'email' => 'admin@admin.fr',
                'adresse' => '12 rue Jean Rostand',
                'cp' => 90000,
                'ville' => 'Belfort',
                'password' => bcrypt('admin123'),
                'created_at' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
                'updated_at' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
                'admin' => 1,
            ],
            [
                'name' => 'test',
                'nom' => 'Mennegain',
                'prenom' => 'Mathieu',
                'sexe_id' => 1,
                'email' => 'test@test.fr',
                'adresse' => '12 rue Jean Rostand',
                'cp' => 90000,
                'ville' => 'Belfort',
                'password' => bcrypt('test123'),
                'created_at' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
                'updated_at' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
                'admin' => 0,
            ]
        ]);
    }
}
```

My database seeder :

```
class DatabaseSeeder extends Seeder
{
    /**
     * Run the database seeds.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function run()
    {
        $this->call(SexesTableSeeder::class);
        $this->call(UsersTableSeeder::class);
        $this->call(SaisonTableSeeder::class);
        $this->call(ProduitTypeSeeder::class);
        $this->call(SportsTableSeeder::class);
        $this->call(ProduitsTableSeeder::class);
    }
}
```

When i run : php artisan migrate:refresh -seed

I have this error :

```
 [Illuminate\Database\QueryException]                                         
  SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1215 Cannot add foreign key constraint (SQL  
  : alter table `users` add constraint `users_sexe_id_foreign` foreign key (`  
  sexe_id`) references `sexes` (`id`))                                         



  [PDOException]                                                          
  SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1215 Cannot add foreign key constraint
```

Comment: make sure your database engine is `InnoDB`, `MyISAM` does not support foreign keys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The order of migrations is super important. From what you posted you run the users migration first and in that same migration you try to create a users table and alter a table. the other table `sexes` doesn't exist

```
($table->foreign('sexe_id')->references('id')->on('sexes');)
```

so that is why you get a error.

I suggest separating the migrations in order to run users, sexes, alter users or sexes, users and alter in the same migration, but this is not a good way to do things, I mean to mix migrations (create and alter).

Answer (score 0):

Probably there are nothing with `id` 1 in `sexes` table and `sexe_id` => 1 generating this error. In your `UsersTableSeeder` rather than hardcoding `'sexe_id' => 1` query your `sexes` table for any row and use that dynamic `id`.